# Opening a huge .csv file with Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an application that write huge .csv files about the size ranging from 1 GB to 2 GB.

I need to color code the file and save it as .xlsx.

So I have tried using Excel Interop and it works great for small files, but when I try to open a 1.3 GB .csv file with Excel, I get an Hresult error.

Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this task either with using Excel, or if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: I ran into a problem a week or two ago where Excel 2003 could not handle more than 65536 lines per worksheet, so only a partial file could ever be displayed (our solution was to split the file before it hit the 65536 line limit). There were similar limits to the number of columns, but since I didn't hit that, I don't know what that nubmer is ;)
 Just an FYI...

Comment: What Excel version are you using, and what error code do you get exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Are you exceeding 1M rows ? 
Maybe thats the reason for the HRESULT error.

64K rows max before Excel 2007. 1M rows for 2007

Comment: Excel 2007 also maxes out? I'd heard "unlimited" from a coworker, but I guess they just didn't have enough data! ;)

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/ha100778231033.aspx - In Excel 2007, the worksheet size is 16,384 columns by 1,048,576 rows, but the worksheet size of earlier versions of Excel is only 256 columns by 65,536 rows.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Surely Excel 2007 has a limit as well, any machine has limited resources (and one boundary here is the 2 GB memory limit for a 32-bit process). In fact, large Excel sheets are one of the reasons that there is now a 64-bit version of Office coming with Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to write and read excel files without using the excel interop. I'm pretty sure I remember microsoft themself have open specifications on the excel fileformat.

Comment: Ah never mind, it's probably like above said, split the files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys, after thinking about it, I have decided to simply use the .csv file.